# crontab task creating protected files - i don't want them protected

Tags: python, cron

I use crontab to run my python scripts. The end results are csv files.

But when I run them with sudo crontab -e, the resulting files are protected.
Is there any way to set crontab schedule and not protect the resulting files?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo crontab -e` will run all items in that crontab as root. Any resulting files will be owned by root.

`crontab -e` (without `sudo`) will run all items in that crontab as that user (not root). Any resulting files will be owned by that user.